# Cross-Domain image urls via WebGL not working

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-domain, webgl

I am having a difficult time trying to get images to appear that are from other domains via WebGL. I've looked at many tutorials online but they don't seem to work (they all seem to be from 2011 and/or aimed for chrome 13/mozilla firefox 5). I have chrome 28 and mozilla firefox 21.0 . Here is some of my code:

```
function main() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        render(image);
    }
    image.crossOrigin = "use-credentials";
    image.src = "http://mediaserver.pulse2.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/google-maps-logo.png";
}
```

I've replaced "use-credentials" with "anonymous" and it still doesn't work. There isn't any error messages, only a blank screen shows up.

If you can help, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Does mediaserver.pulse2.com serve up the correct CORS headers?  If not then you won't be able to do it until they do.

Comment: I see - that helps, thanks :) I'll just use a website that has correct CORS headers - I think they are on this - http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#Who_is_doing_it_already.3F ?

Comment: Never mind, I think I found one that is CORS for images - http://remysharp.com/2013/01/14/cors-isnt-just-for-xhr/ thanks!